# Receiving an image as blob from server converting back to image with Objective-C fails

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, blob

My service returns the following which is a blob representing an image:

```
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
```

In Oobjective-C I'm trying to convert it back to an image and I get exception, I even tried saving it to a file testing different extensions (png, jpg, jpeg, bmp) nothing worked the only way the file opens is with a txt extension.

How can I convert this blob into the image it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like Base64 encoded JPEG image data, so this should work:

```
NSString *b64String = @"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASA ..."; // your string from the server

NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:b64String options:0];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

`initWithBase64EncodedString` is available since iOS 7.0. If you want to target
earlier iOS versions, you can use the following method instead:

```
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64Encoding:b64String];
```

Comment: is there a special import i should add cause i get compile error:
No visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'initWithBase64Encoding

Comment: This should work with the newest Xcode 5.0.2 and the iOS 7.0 SDK. (initWithBase64Encoding is available since iOS 4, but was never documented in the SDK before.) - Alternatively, you can use any of the publicly available Base64 decoders for Objective-C, such as https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64.

Comment: I've read the documentation, but the function doesn't appear in NSData.h im working with xcode 4.6 and IOS 6

Comment: @liva: As I explained in my previous comment, the method was *available* but *not documented* in previous versions of the SDK. - The main point is that your server sends Base64 encoded data, and you have to decode that first. There are some Base64 decoders for Objective-C available, such as the one that I mentioned above.